# labels in pagination Superslides

Tags: javascript, pagination, label

I'm using the Superslides plugin: https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides

Now I want to add labelling to the pagination.

So what the result should look like is the standardpagination, only the label/title shows when you hover an item.

I don't know where to add this in the code, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you. https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides/issues/75

I would change current css for .slides-pagination to this:

```
.slides-pagination a {
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
vertical-align: middle;
*vertical-align: auto;
zoom: 1;
margin: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: -100%;
}
```

And the current is up to you... Remember to change also what is in line 378 (in the js) to this: 'text': 'test' + href